# How do I apply a border radius to Bootstrap 3's tables?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the top corners and bottom corners of a table to have rounded corners.

How can I do this?  Right now, the Bootstrap 3 tables have 0 radius.

Comment: How about `border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius` etc properties ? Aren't they working ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<table class="table table-curved">
    ....
</table>    

.table-curved {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.table-curved {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:0px;
}
.table-curved td, .table-curved th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table-curved th {
    border-top: none;
}
.table-curved th:first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.table-curved th:only-child{
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.table-curved tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is there an extra border on the top?

Comment: To get rid of the space between the columns I used border-collapse: collapse

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is wrap the table with a panel. Then your table will have rounded corners automatically.

Example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <table class="table table-striped">
      ....
   </table>
</div>
```

Note: panel-default will add a 1px grey border. if you want to hide it just add border-color:white; to style of panel-default.